# Where is the place that discord bots can store information [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I am not too new to python but new to discord.py. I have tried to go through the discord.py manual but did not find where I can store some temporary variable on a discord bot.

discord.py manual: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

For example, in PHP SESSION, we can store information on the SESSION(). Did discord.py has the same kind of things?

For example, if we have user "A" and user "B". "A" will be stored as an object of "A_Object", such as messages etc. Similar for "B_Object" but will be different from "A_Object". In discord.py, is there a function like that?

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use sqlite database. Write inside your def:

```
# define database
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("my_database.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
# get stored object from database
sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE field_1=?"
cursor.execute(sql, [(value_1)])
data = cursor.fetchall()
# if object does not exist, create it
if len(data) == 0:
    sql = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (?, ?)"
    cursor.execute(sql, [(value_1), (value_2)])
# if stored object exist and we need update it
elif ...:
    sql = "UPDATE my_table SET field_2 = ? WHERE field_1 = ?"
    cursor.execute(sql, [(value_2), (value_1)])
else:
    # get data from first object
    value_of_field_1 = data[0][0]
    # get data from third object
    value_of_field_2 = data[2][1]
# close database connection
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

my_database.db - is a sqlite db file and should be stored in sa same folder with bot's .py file.

Comment: I was kind of looking for the communication place where the data can store with the specific user.

Comment: The field_1 can be a user identifier

Comment: Thanks for answering, I think I probably did not explain clearly. The goal I wanted is more like being able to distinguish the user who is talking with the bot and have a different place to store his/her personal data. It is like my updated question if you do not mind to read. I currently using JSON to store, but the bot can't distinguish the user's information.

Comment: Still gonna accept this since this is the only answer :)

Comment: what kind of personal data did you mean?

Comment: It was long passed, but I was wanting to have a "user info" stored. Now I know I can use database or whatever file to store it :)