# Discord bot with user specific counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Discord bot in Python that a user can request a unit every few minutes, and later ask the bot how many units they have. Would creating a google spreadsheet for the bot to write each user's number of units to be a good idea, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is your question "Can I used google spreadsheet as a data store?". I would advise you look at storing your data into a database.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242689/where-is-the-place-that-discord-bots-can-store-information-discord-py/45252017#45252017

Comment: Seems like a job for a database to me. Maybe two tables? `User` and `UserPoints` with an xref between?

Comment: Here's some temperamental (and not debugged) sample code. I don't think this is worthy of an answer in the short time I have to work on it, but [your mileage may vary](https://repl.it/repls/ElaborateExhaustedAssemblylanguage). NOTE: your code will want to use a filesystem-backed database, not `:memory:` as mine does, since you won't want the units to reset every time the bot restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Using a database is the best option. If you're working with a small number of users and requests you could use something even simpler like a text file for ease of use, but I'd recommend a database.

Easy to use database options include sqlite (use the sqlite3 python library) and MongoDB (I use the mongoengine python library for my Slack bot).