# Python Bot Commands total count

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How to add a code which tracks all commands total counts from all servers bot has been installed. example for below command i need counts how many time this command has been used in all server and from all user.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def first(ctx):
     await bot.say("Hello {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

.

```
final result this Command has been used xx times from users all servers.
```

Comment: Obviously you just add 1 to some number stored somehwere.  So the real question is "Where can I store information from a discord bot?": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242689/where-is-the-place-that-discord-bots-can-store-information-discord-py/45252017#45252017

Comment: Ok i need to add `bot.counter += 1`  and for your link Do i need to add that code in bot or in `my_database.db` file ?

Comment: That's python code.

Answer (score 1):

Well why not make a database of like sqlite?? or even use json to store , like in json you can store something like {"command1":1,"command2":2} and then in end of each code it adds a json.load attribute to import the file and update it , Easy